# How does XMonad keys functions gets reduced?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm trying to understand how XMonad configuration functions are evaluated. The first example is from Xmonad [docs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips):

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
--

main = xmonad $ defaultConfig {
  --
  , keys          = \c -> mykeys c `M.union` keys defaultConfig c
  --
  }
where
    mykeys (XConfig {modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
         [ ((modm , xK_x), spawn "xlock") ]
```

The type of keys is a function:
`keys :: !(XConfig Layout -> Map (ButtonMask, KeySym) (X ()))`
The question here is evaluation order. `keys` returns Map when applied to some `XConfig`, and then Map we've got should be applied to `c` (if I get it right), but how Map can be applied to something?

Comment: Easy: you haven't got the right type for `keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description isn't quite correct. `keys` is a record field.

When you have a record type `R` with a field `foo :: T`, then `foo` itself (used as a value) has the type `R -> T` (it's a record accessor function).

Since `keys` is a field of `XConfig`, its type is actually

```
keys :: XConfig l -> !(XConfig Layout -> Map (ButtonMask, KeySym) (X ()))
```

In

```
keys defaultConfig c
```

We extract the `keys` field from `defaultConfig`. The value stored in this field is itself a function, which we apply to `c` to get a `Map`.

Comment: Thank you, `data XConfig` source code made it totally clear for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` is not a function; it's a data structure, and it doesn't get applied to anything. Instead, you are creating a new config, based on `defaultConfig`, with its `keys` function replace with a new anonymous function. *That* function takes a configuration, and applies two functions to it: your `mikeys`, and whatever function `keys defaultConfig` returns. The two resulting `Maps` are merged and returned by your configuration's `key` function.

`xmonad` then uses this new configuration, which involves extracting the merged `Map` to set up your key bindings.